# Datetime conversion in web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime

I have a asp.net web application using SQL Server 2012 as the database.

The web server currently has american date time format. The code of the web application passed datetime values as NOW and all works fine.

Now I was trying to deploy this web application by using a clean machine (for internal testing). The web application worked fine again. The problem came when I tries to pass a datetime value to the SQL Server. The error is

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

To fix the problem I change the datetime format of the machine to American date time format because that is what the first server did. Unfortunately it still does not run.

Any ideas what all can I try?

To Update my code

My SQL Server has user defined type

```
MyDataTable.Rows.Add(
                    batchNoRow[0], //Batch ID
                    DateTime.Now, //Creation Date
                    );

// Then pass the table type in a stored procedure as below

SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@Array", MyDataTable);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); 
cmd.connection = myconnection;
cmd.CommandText = mycommandText;
cmd.CommandType = commandType;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The definition of @array is a user defined type in sql server

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[MyTableType] AS TABLE(
    [BatchNo] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
   [BatchNo] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF)
)
GO
```

Comment: Some code would help

Comment: Pass instances of the datetime struct to the sql server, this way you don't need to worry about string representation default format stuff at all.

Comment: Store the data in the Database as DateTime instead of a string.

Comment: SELECT convert(datetime, cast(value as varchar),104)

Comment: @MightyBadaboom please see my code

Comment: Neither SQL Server nor ASP.NET change any formats because date types have **no** format. They are binary values. Just *don't* use strings instead of dates. Use date-typed parameters.

Comment: I am not using strings. I am using DateTime.Now

Comment: Is `@Array` a TVP? What is its definition? Could the order of the fields be reversed? Does it contain a `datetime` field for the date?

Comment: I have updated my question again with the definition of @Array

Comment: @user2837961 if you did, you wouldn't get that error. You are using strings somewhere. You haven't posted any of the *relevant* code though - table and TVP schema, definition of `MyDataTable`. Somewhere in all of them you are using `nvarchar` instead of `datetime`

Comment: @user2837961 post the table schema and the *query*. If you use a stored procedure, post the stored procedure code too. If SQL Server had any kind of problem with dates, people would have noticed 20 years ago. What *does* happen all the time is people using strings instead of dates, build queries with string concatenation or somehow generate strings in their code without noticing

Comment: What's the columns definition of your c# DataTable (`MyDataTable`)?

Comment: @ZoharPeled Thanks for giving the hint. My definition of datatable did not have types hence it was going as a string

Comment: Glad to help. Please answer your own question (or would you like me to post an answer?) and accept it so that other people will know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have `DataTable` setup as this:

```
var MyDataTable = new DataTable();
MyDataTable.Columns.Add("BatchNo");
MyDataTable.Columns.Add("CreationDate");
```

Without specifying data type for columns added in `DataTable`, `DataColumn` assumes that data type is `String` by default [(see MSDN reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c5wf85e.aspx#setdatatype).

> Data columns (DataColumn) are created with a default data type of
>   String.

Hence, the value returned by `DateTime.Now` stored as date string, then converted to SQL as `nvarchar`, thereby throwing `SqlException` since target `CreationDate` column in TVP declared as `datetime`.

To ensure passed values have proper data types, specify data type for each column in `DataTable` as this:

```
MyDataTable.Columns.Add("BatchNo", typeof(int));
MyDataTable.Columns.Add("CreationDate", typeof(DateTime));
```

NB: You can't change or alter `DataType` after `DataTable` has filled with data, so that `DataType` for every column(s) must be specified **before** adding row(s).